# How do I unhide a section in the Umbraco admin panel?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-mvc

I'm new to Umbraco - while playing and trying to explore from the admin area, I have hidden the `Users` and `Members` sections. Now, the `Members` and `Users` sections are not visible in the admin section. I am logged in using the master/admin account.

How I can unhide these sections? I want to bring them back and make them visible in the admin section.

Comment: Are you able to navigate to http://yoursite.com/umbraco#/users?

Answer (score 0):

In your backoffice, click left on the round circle with the head inside to get to your user settings. 
From there you should be able to edit your profile settings by pressing the green "Edit" button.
In your profile settings, there should be a group called "sections". Verify that your "Users" and "Members" sections have a checkmark there.

Comment: You will need to log out in back in again for the sections to show up for you though.